# Emacs: CUA mode. Paste(yank) in minibuffer not work

Tags: emacs

Emacs 24.5, turn on CUA mode.
My binding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)
```

I want paste(yank) by **C-v** in minibuffer in 2 cases:

1. **M-x** and then paste(C-v) some text
2. I-search (**C-f**) and then paste(C-v) some text

Is this a possible in CUA mode?

Comment: Problem is that Helm mode overrides the cua-mode binding of C-v. Helm documentation: You can navigate the buffer with C-n and C-p or <up> and <down> to move up/down, C-v and M-v to move to next/previous pages, and M-< and M-> to move to the top and bottom of the Helm buffer.

Comment: Is there no Helm option or workaround to let you use `C-v` in the cua-mode way in the minibuffer? If not, consider filing a Helm enhancement request.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution from: http://tahirhassan.blogspot.kr/2014/01/emacs-cua-mode-and-isearch.html

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-v") 'isearch-yank-kill)
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

- `M-x C-v` works fine, with `emacs -Q` (no init file).
- `C-s C-v` does not - it seems that `cua-mode` does not affect Isearch - just use `C-y` instead of `C-v`.  If you want a change in that regard (i.e., an improvement for `cua-mode` with Isearch), consider filing an Emacs enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.
- If the problem is introduced by using Helm (which it seems to be), consider filing a Helm bug report or asking Helm support. (But maybe someone here can tell you how to handle that.)

Comment: Isearch works with `cua-mode` with `isearch-edit-string`, so `C-s M-e C-v` should make it.